# How to check with an IF inside a FOR loop whether a row of an sql query meets a certain criteria or not using Python

Tags: python, sql

i am pretty new at Python, and i encountered this problem i am not beeing able to solve.

I am trying to save diferent csv for diferent brands, my code is this:

```
import pyodbc
import csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cur = cnxn.cursor()

BRANDS=pd.read_sql_query("""
SELECT BRAND, COUNT(1) AS COUNT
FROM DATABASE
GROUP BY BRAND
""",cnxn)

data=pd.DataFrame(BRANDS,columns=['BRAND','COUNT'])

for i in data["BRAND"]:
       
    ROUT="my rout"
    file_name = ROUT+"NAME"+ str(i) +".csv" 
    
    sql =pd.read_sql_query( """
    SELECT A, B, BRAND
    FROM DATABASE 
    """,cnxn)
    QUERY=pd.DataFrame(sql,columns=['A','B','BRAND'])

    with open(file_name, "w", newline='') as f:
       
        wrtr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        
        for row in QUERY:
            if str(QUERY["BRAND"])==str(i):
               wrtr.writerow(row[A,B])
```

How can i only write the two first columns of a row and only when the brand of the row matches the brand of the first for loop

Comment: `QUERY["BRAND"]` is a whole column, you dont' want to compare to this i guess

Comment: I'd recommend considering using `while` loop, if you need to check any conditions after each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has filtering that means you don't even need to iterate through rows.  You can iterate through your `BRAND`s and make a filtered dataframe for just that brand's rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

#Will set up some dummy data here
brands = ['nike','reebok','addidas']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), 
    columns=['A','B'])
df['BRAND'] = [random.choice(brands) for x in range(100)]
#print(df)

#With your "A,B,BRAND" dataframe, go from here
#get unique values in the BRAND column and iterate through them
for brand in df['BRAND'].unique():
    #create a filtered copy of the dataframe for this individual brand 
    brand_df = df[df['BRAND'] == brand].copy()
    #print(brand_df)
    #drop the BRAND column so that only A and B columns remain 
    brand_df.drop(columns=['BRAND'], inplace=True)
    #can also use pandas builtin csv writer
    brand_df.to_csv(brand+'.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

Comment: Consider a `groupby` loop and avoid `unique` with `[==`: `for n, g in df.groupby("BRAND")` where `n` is name of group and `g` subsetted data frame.